# Can one sfmc connect to multiple sales crm?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcedx

We have 2 of each test uat and qa env and then one prod. However, we are still procuring sfmc instances and wondering if we truly need that many corresponding instances. Can one sfmc connect to multiple sales crm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, you simply need to ask support to enable Multi-org Marketing Cloud Connect to be able to connect one SFMC instance to multiple CRM instances (no matter if prod or sandbox). You will then be able to connect individual SFMC business units to your CRM orgs, eg. BU1 connected to QA sandbox, BU2 connected to UAT sandbox, BU3 connected to PROD org, etc. Note, that one BU can only be connected to one SF org at one time.

In my opinion, connecting that many test/qa environments to SFMC is an overkill, you will struggle to keep them all up to date, so I’d suggest talking to a SFMC architect about a sustainable org strategy. In my experience, one test/qa business unit is enough and you don’t need as many as many as SF sandboxes you have.

> Multi-Org is an Enterprise 2.0 account configuration. This
> configuration allows individual Marketing Cloud business units to
> connect with a single Salesforce org, independent of the parent
> account or other business units. Using Marketing Cloud Connect, this
> configuration includes two setup scenarios:
>
> - Multiple business units connected to multiple orgs.
> - Multiple business units connected to a single org.

Make sure to go through the documentation to be aware of all constraints and best practices:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&language=en_US